# AttributeError: /usr/sbin/httpd: undefined symbol: Error_GetLastErrorNum with Flask and mod_wsgi

Tags: python, mod-wsgi

I have a website that runs python code with Flask and mod_wsgi.  I set the WSGIDaemonProcess user and group and the WSGIProcessGroup.  Recently, after updating geopandas, I have been getting the error  AttributeError: /usr/sbin/httpd: undefined symbol: Error_GetLastErrorNum with Flask and mod_wsgi when the wgsi file imports the python app which tries to import geopandas.

The full text from the httpd error log is

File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/**init**.py", line 1, in

from geopandas._config import options  # noqa
File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/_config.py", line 109, in

default_value=_default_use_pygeos(),
File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/_config.py", line 95, in _default_use_pygeos

import geopandas._compat as compat
File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/_compat.py", line 217, in 
import rtree  # noqa
File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rtree/**init**.py", line 9, in

from .index import Rtree, Index  # noqa
File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rtree/index.py", line 6, in 
from . import core

File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rtree/core.py", line 77, in 
rt.Error_GetLastErrorNum.restype = ctypes.c_int

File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/ctypes/**init**.py", line 386, in **getattr**
func = self.**getitem**(name)

File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/ctypes/**init**.py", line 391, in **getitem**
func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
tributeError: /usr/sbin/httpd: undefined symbol: Error_GetLastErrorNum

Note, that I have tried running the individual commands such as import geopandas, rt.Error_GetLastErrorNum.restype = ctypes.c_int and other both as the user specified in the conf file, as root, and as apache.  I can't reproduce the error.  It only occurs when I try to open the website  Selinux is set to permissive.

Comment: **rtree** is an optional package that will be loaded when you use spatial indexes, e.g. `sjoin()`. Have you verified it is installed and has correct permissions?  see https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/install.html wrt optional packages

Comment: Yes, as stated in the question, I ran the command rt.Error_GetLastErrorNum.restype = ctypes.c_int, which is in rtree/core.py line 77.  Before testing the command, I verified the installation.

Comment: the point I'm making is **rtree** is a *lazy* import,  i.e. only imported when it's needed, not at point **geopandas** is imported.  It's worth trying to import it as well as geopandas in your testing.

Comment: For my testing, I created a simple hello world app.  It fails with the same errors when I import geopandas or rtree.  I am able to import rtree as any other user I have access to, with the same python environment I specify in WSGIDaemonProcess in my httpd conf file

Comment: not clear what it is.  If this was an issue I was having I would completely tear down the condo env and re-create from scratch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that mod_wsgi was installed with yum.  This created it's own python environment, which mod_wsgi defaulted to, and was trying to load ctypes from.  Geopandas, rtree, etc were being loaded from the miniconda env.  The solution was

```
dnf remove mod_wsgi
dnf install httd-devel
```

Then from the desired python env

```
pip install mod_wsgi
sudo mod_wsgi-express install-module
```

Then insert the output in the desired httpd .conf file.